# Register generic where T is in specific namespace

Tags: c#, autofac

I currently have something like this:

```
new ContainerBuilder()
      .RegisterGeneric(typeof(MyFactory<>))
      .As(typeof(IMyFactory<>))
      .WithParameter("param", "abc")
      .SingleInstance();
```

I would like to limit the above where T (in `MyFactory<T>`) is in a specific namespace.

Is this possible with `RegisterGeneric()`?  If I use `RegisterAssemblyTypes()` then I should be able to use `Where(type => type.IsInNamespace("..."))` and individually register each type.

Is that the recommended approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this. By the way you can use the `OnActivating` event to replace an instance based on the namespace of your type.

Let say you have types in different namespace :

```
public interface IFoo
{ }
namespace X
{
    public class FooX : IFoo { }
}
namespace Y
{
    public class FooY : IFoo { }
}
```

And 1 generic `Factory` and 2 specific :

```
public interface IFooFactory<TFoo>
    where TFoo : IFoo
{
    TFoo Create();
}

public class XFactory<TFoo> : IFooFactory<TFoo>
    where TFoo : IFoo
{
    public TFoo Create()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class YFactory<TFoo> : IFooFactory<TFoo>
    where TFoo : IFoo
{
    public TFoo Create()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class DefaultFactory<TFoo> : IFooFactory<TFoo>
    where TFoo : IFoo
{
    public TFoo Create()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can register your specific factories like this :

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(XFactory<>))
       .Named("ProjectNamespace.X", typeof(IFooFactory<>));
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(YFactory<>))
       .Named("ProjectNamespace.Y", typeof(IFooFactory<>));
```

And your generic factory like this :

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(DefaultFactory<>))
        .As(typeof(IFooFactory<>))
        .OnActivating(e =>
        {
            Type elementType = e.Instance.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
            Type fooFactoryType = typeof(IFooFactory<>).MakeGenericType(elementType); 
            Service service = new KeyedService(elementType.Namespace, fooFactoryType);
            Object fooFactory = e.Context.ResolveOptionalService(service, e.Parameters);
            if (fooFactory != null)
            {
                e.ReplaceInstance(fooFactory);
            }
        });
```

Only the default factory is registered as `IFooFactory<>`. If you try to resolve a `IFooFactory<X.FooX>` then `OnActivating` event will replace the default factory instance and you will obtain a `XFooFactory<X.FooX>`

The main drawback of this is that a `DefaultFactory<>` will be instanciated each time. It can be a problem if this registration depends on other or if the initialization takes time.

Comment: You said `DefaultFooFactory` would be instantiated each time, which I take you were referring to `DefaultFactory<>`.  Are you implying that `XFactory<>` wouldn't be instantiated each time because they don't use `OnActivating`?  Either way `XFactory<>`  would have to go through the `OnActivating` logic every time it's needed if I'm not mistaken.  This seems essentially like an abstract factory but instead of implementing it in a separate class you have the logic in `OnActivating` and of course can make use of the named registrations.

Comment: The factories are expensive to create and used frequently so if `XFactory<>` in your example would be instantiated every time this wouldn't be a good idea.  If not, I could ensure that `DefaultFactory<>` never gets run which of course would make that part pointless.  I could do a separate abstract factory with this logic to avoid `DefaultFactory<>`, but then I would have to store the instances myself and couldn't easily control the lifetime which is the point of Autofac.